# Dictionary of dictionaries design in C#

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

My question: is there a canonical way of creating a dictionary of dictionaries and providing an outer/inner key pair?  Is there a NugetPackage out there with an implementation?

In my code, I have now a few places where I have a property like this

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, SomeType>> _nestedDict = 
        new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, SomeType>>();
```

and I've created extension methods like this

```
public static V AddOrUpdate<T, U, V>(
    [NotNull] this IDictionary<T, IDictionary<U, V>> dictionary,
    [NotNull] T outerKey,
    [NotNull] U innerKey,
    [NotNull] Func<V> addValueFactory,
    [NotNull] Func<V, V> updateValueFactory,
    [CanBeNull] IEqualityComparer<U> innerDictionaryComparer = null)
{
    IDictionary<U, V> dict;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(outerKey, out dict))
    {
        V currentValue;
        if (dict.TryGetValue(innerKey, out currentValue))
        {
            var updatedValue = updateValueFactory(currentValue);
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(updatedValue, currentValue))
                dict[innerKey] = updatedValue;
            return updatedValue;
        }
        var addedValue1 = addValueFactory();
        dict[innerKey] = addedValue1;
        return addedValue1;
    }

    var addedValue = addValueFactory();
    if (innerDictionaryComparer != null)
        dictionary[outerKey] = new Dictionary<U, V>(innerDictionaryComparer) {{innerKey, addedValue}};
    else
        dictionary[outerKey] = new Dictionary<U, V> {{innerKey, addedValue}};
    return addedValue;
}
```

This is powerful, but I'm starting to feel like I should just make a class for nested dictionaries.  Here's my thinking:

1. The `addValueFactory` and `updateValueFactory` are sort of clumsy and it feels like it's breaking OO principles.
2. I am thinking about creating a `ConcurrentDictionary` of `Dictionary`s (or perhaps of `ConcurrentDictionary`s), and this would require some more extension methods.  I sort of thought if I'm using it this much that I should just create the darn class and be done with it.

What say you?

Comment: How useful is the extension method?  I'm all for doing things "right," but I prefer doing things *effectively.*  If it makes sense to create the class, then create the class.  If you can't decide, simpler is always better, all other things being equal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey as simple as possible, but no simpler, is wise.  I was just wondering if anyone had a class that they knew about, perhaps in a NugetPackage that's easily accessible (and already tested)

Comment: Or perhaps I could make one, if no one else knows about one

Comment: I would just define my own type MultiKeyDictionary<k, s, v>... Where k = key, s = sub, v = value. Then create an extension method as you have done.

Comment: Do you really need a dictionary of dictionaries or would Dictionary<Tuple<T,U>, V> work?

Comment: All, I think you have a point and I may be over-engineering this problem at this point.  I think a Dictionary (or `ConcurrentDictionary`) with `Tuple` keys may be the easiest. I'll get good bang for the buck with this design I think

Comment: You sure you can't just define a class and use a dictionary with instances of that class?

Comment: Is the extension method just overly generic or do you actually use keys of type `string` most of the time? Depending on your exact requirements, you might get away with simply concatenating the inner and outer key and use one single Dictionary.

Comment: @null that runs into problems with collisions. "outer", "inner" and "out", "erinner" for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a simpler way towards it.

Consider this:

```
    public class NAryDictionary<TKey, TValue> :
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
    }

    public class NAryDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue> :
        Dictionary<TKey1, NAryDictionary<TKey2, TValue>>
    {
    }

    public class NAryDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3, TValue> :
        Dictionary<TKey1, NAryDictionary<TKey2, TKey3, TValue>>
    {
    }
```

Then you can write:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dico3 = new NAryDictionary<bool, int, string, decimal>();

            dico3[false] = new NAryDictionary<int, string, decimal>();
            dico3[false][123] = new NAryDictionary<string, decimal>();
            dico3[false][123]["foo"] = 123456789.012m;

            Console.WriteLine(dico3[false][123]["foo"].ToString("0,0.000"));

            Console.ReadKey();
       }
    }
```

Now, although it's Visual Studio intellisense-friendly (as you'll notice with automatic code completion proposals after typing the " = " signs in the above assignments), it is arguably a bit cumbersome, still, because of those

```
... new NAryDictionary<bool, int, string, decimal>()
... new NAryDictionary<int, string, decimal>()
```

and

```
... new NAryDictionary<string, decimal>()
```

Which can be alleviated with,

```
    public static class NAryDictionaryExtensions
    {
        public static NAryDictionary<TKey2, TValue> New<TKey1, TKey2, TValue>(this NAryDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TValue> dictionary)
        {
            return new NAryDictionary<TKey2, TValue>();
        }

        public static NAryDictionary<TKey2, TKey3, TValue> New<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3, TValue>(this NAryDictionary<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3, TValue> dictionary)
        {
            return new NAryDictionary<TKey2, TKey3, TValue>();
        }
    }
```

allowing now to write, more simply,

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dico3 = new NAryDictionary<bool, int, string, decimal>();

            dico3[true] = dico3.New();
            dico3[true][456] = dico3[true].New();
            dico3[true][456]["bar"] = 456789012.345m;

            Console.WriteLine(dico3[true][456]["bar"].ToString("0,0.000"));

            Console.ReadKey();
       }
    }
```

'Hope this helps.